# Ubuntu 18.10 has experienced an internal error

Tags: dbus

I am getting this popup after each startup, even on newly installed Ubuntu. I have tried reinstalling over 5 times, and the same error just keeps popping up.

I am trying to figure out what it is, so when I click "show details" I see:

- ExecutablePath: `/usr/bin/dbus-daemon`
- Package: `dbus 1.12.10-1ubuntu2`
- ProblemType: `crash`
- Architecture: `amd64`

What is causing this? If you need further information, I will try to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` will provide additional information
You could narrow it down by using `grep`

`grep dbus-daemon /var/log/syslog`
and
`dmesg | grep dbus-daemon`

Comment: With all due respect, this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I am not allowed to comment due to lack of reputation.. thanks for the downvote to make it harder to comment in the future.

Comment: Sorry about that, lets try to make it up.

Comment: No problem. I don't mind deleting my "answer" if you want to comment for me. I realize I'm not solving the issue, but it's where the OP should start.

Comment: I was just contemplating that, wondering what hardware/firmware/bios/ACPI malfeasance could be at the bottom of this issue.  the output of:


>/var/log/syslog and dmesg will provide additional information You could narrow it down by using grep

>grep dbus-daemon /var/log/syslog and dmesg | grep dbus-daemon